# Перевод результата запроса в массив строк

Tags: postgresql, база-данных, java, синтаксис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом перегнать результаты выполнения хранимой процедуры на `postgresql`, да и вообще, каков синтаксис вызова хранимой процедуры базы `postgresql` на `java`, которая читает пути (к директориям или файлам) из некоторой таблицы базы в массив строк.

Comment: JDBC, Hibernate

Comment: мне кажется полезно будет почитать мануалы к jdbc + к драйверу постгреса. ответить на вопрос крайне сложно, хотя бы потому что нет информации о структуре вашей таблицы

Comment: @jmu, какая разница в структуре? jdbc достаточно что бы подключится к любой БД

Comment: а запросы как писать будете? на кофейной гуще гадать будем?

Comment: @jmu, я их писать не буду и ты не будешь, это не принципиально в контексте вопроса

Comment: 2 Gorets: возможно я неправильно выразился, но я хотел сказать следующее:

что на так поставленный вопрос напрашивается ответ: RTFM , этого будет достаточно  
а для того чтоб предоставить более развернутый ответ надо больше информации

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = null;
try {
   String SQL = "{call getEmpName (?, ?)}";
   cstmt = conn.prepareCall (SQL);
   . . .
}
catch (SQLException e) {
   . . .
}
finally {
   . . .
}
```

Найдено [здесь](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-stored-procedure.htm).
Почитайте еще [это](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html).

Если коротко - если вы делаете запросы к БД, то ответ приходит в виде объекта `ResultSet`. Это абстракция ответа, по которой можно ходить итератором.